# When using jquery ui droppable, is there any way to specific if you want a div inside that is not droppable instead of that?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using [jquery ui sortable with connectswith](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists).  It works perfectly except for one issue.  I have a heading section  (div) inside the area and I want to see if i can exclude this area from being droppable.

```
<ul id="Ul2" class="initsortableList">
       <div class="heading">Name </div>
</ul>

$(".initsortableList").sortable({
    connectWith: ".initconnectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

Is there anyway the "heading" class can be excluded from being droppable?

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this by setting the selector of child items that should be enabled to sortable. So let say you element that shall be active for sort has `class="sortable"` and the one disabled fort sort has `class="header"`. You just specify this in the parameter `items` in the sortable(). [Read more](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items)